# initialise a deque of vector pointers

Tags: c++, stl, vector, deque

```
class MD { 
    MD();
    MD(const MD &obj);
    MD& operator=(const MD &obj);
  private:
    int Name;
    double sal;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<MD> mDataPtr;
typedef std::vector<mDataPtr> mDataVecContr;
typedef std::shared_ptr<mDataVecContr> ptrMdataVecContr;

class MDataContainer{
  public:
    MDataContainer();
    MDataContainer(const MDataContainer &mDataCont);
    MDataContainer& operator=(const MDataContainer &mDataCont);

  private:
    mDataVecContr vecNode;
    std::deque<ptrMdataVectContr> mDataQueContr;
};
```

My requirement is to store 500 object of type MD in a vector then I am keeping pointer to these vectors in deque. The problem here is how to initialize this list in copy contructor MDataContainer(const MDataContainer &mDataCont) and assign it in overloaded assignment operator MDataContainer& operator=(const MDataContainer &mDataCont). To get rid of code duplication I am using Init function. Pls explain me a method which can give better performance. Some rough way I am already using. Can we have some algo or some other library(boost I am not having gr8 idea) which can be used to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: Don't rly get what you want to do. How about posting the "slow" code you already have.

Comment: w817, are you having 1 vector with 500 entries and a deque with 1 entry in which there is a pointer to your vector or are you having a deque of pointers to vectors and 1 extra vector on the side?  And basically you want an efficient way to copy MDataContainer?

Comment: What is wrong with the compiler generated copy constructor? In the example code you have given the compiler will generate a copy constructor and copy assignment operator (if you don't define them yourself) that should do the right thing for you.

Comment: @ its deque of pointers to vectors (not single vector in the deque).

Comment: @Bowie Owens  it contain too much of pointers in it and shallow copy is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to reconsider your design if you want a deep copy.  If you have a deque containing 10(arbitrarily picked number) shared pointers to vectors of 500 shared pointers of MD objects, a copy constructor is going to require 5021 allocations from the heap, minimum, which is going to be bulky.  Are you sure you need smart pointers to the vectors, and to the MD objects?  If not, the number of allocations could be brought down to 11 with `std::deque<std::vector<MD>> mDataQueContr;`

If you do want the deep copy with smart pointers, you'll have to loop through to construct them, as copy constructing a shared_ptr will be a shallow copy.  I haven't looked into shared_ptr yet, but assuming they work like auto_ptr, you want something like this.  I use iterators, because they're faster than indexing on deque.

```
MDataContainer::MDataContainer(const MDataContainer &mDataCont) {
    // initialize the deque to default null shared pointers
    mDataQueContr.resize(mDataCont.mDataQueContr.size());
    // for each super smart pointer
    std::dequeue<ptrMdataVectContr>::iterator destsup = mDataQueContr.begin();
    std::dequeue<ptrMdataVectContr>::const_iterator srcsup;
    srcsup = mDataCont.mDataQueContr.begin();
    for( ; destsup != mDataQueContr.end(); ++destsup,++srcsup) {
        // assign it a new vector of the right size of null shared pointers
        *destsup = new mDataVecContr((*srcsup)->size());
        // for each sub smart pointer
        mDataVecContr::iterator destsub = (*destsup)->begin();
        mDataVecContr::const_iterator srcsub = (*srcsup)->begin();
        for( ; destsub != (*destsup)->end(); ++destsub,++srcsub)
            *destsub = new MD(**srcsub); //assign it a new MD copy
    }
```